# How to get dep ensure to remove unused Go files, dependencies or packages

Tags: go, package, dependency-management, aws-sdk-go, godeps

When adding new dependencies using `dep ensure -add <package>` I see `dep` adding the complete repository of the package, instead of just the parts I require.

For example I added [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) and `dep ensure` put 87MB of files into my vendors folder, even though I only use the AWS Secrets Manager service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve this you need to define `[prune]` settings which determine what files and directories can be deemed unnecessary, and thus automatically removed from vendor/.

The following options are currently available:

- `unused-packages` indicates that files from directories that do not appear in the package import graph should be pruned
- `non-go` prunes files that are not used by Go
- `go-tests` prunes Go test files

Out of an abundance of caution, dep non-optionally preserves files that may have legal significance.

Pruning options are disabled by default. However, generating a `Gopkg.toml` via `dep init` will add lines to enable `go-tests` and `unused-packages` prune options at the root level.

```
[prune]
  go-tests = true
  unused-packages = true
```

The same prune options can be defined per-project. An additional name field is required and, as with `[[constraint]]` and `[[override]]`, should be a [source root](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/glossary.html#source-root), not just any import path.

```
[prune]
  non-go = true

  [[prune.project]]
    name = "github.com/project/name"
    go-tests = true
    non-go = false
```

Almost all projects will be fine without setting any project-specific rules, and enabling the following pruning rules globally:

```
[prune]
  unused-packages = true
  go-tests = true
```

It is usually safe to set `non-go = true`, as well. However, as `dep` only has a clear model for the role played by Go files, and non-Go files necessarily fall outside that model, there can be no comparable general definition of safety.